# Envoy proxy: ExternalProcessor GRPC load balancing possible?

Tags: grpc, load-balancing, envoyproxy

Setup: We are running three istio/envoy pods (each in a separate [AZ](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html#concepts-availability-zones)) which are making ["ExternalProcessor" GRPC calls](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/extensions/filters/http/ext_proc/v3/ext_proc.proto#envoy-v3-api-msg-extensions-filters-http-ext-proc-v3-externalprocessor) to worker pods to add an http header to the original request.

The issue is: even when running six worker pods (two per AZ), only **one** in each AZ receives traffic. I *assume* this is due to the nature of GRPC/http2's long-lived connections.

If my assumption is correct, is it possible to open (at least one) connection to each worker pod (multiple connections from the envoy) and distribute the load evenly?